# Azure Storage authorization failure (Excel and Power BI)

Tags: excel, azure, powerbi, azure-table-storage

I am getting "Access to the resource is forbidden." when trying to connect to an Azure Storage Table using either Excel or Power BI. both applications are logged into the Azure with my institutional account and I have confirmed that I can access and browse the desired data using the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer logged in using the same account.

I am able to navigate to the correct storage account and see the table listed and see the top 100 records without issue using the storage explorer but both Excel and Power BI throw the same error.

**connection error:**

[image]

Under a different account I am an admin on the storage account and am trying to produce a proof of concept for some of our staff that will need to use data from the storage account. The account I am using for the PoC is not the admin account (my regular user account) and has been assigned the Reader and Storage Table Data Reader roles to the storage account.

I have also disabled the "Allow storage account key access" option as we want them using their Azure AD accounts only.

TLDR: I can read the azure storage table using the storage explorer but Excel and Power BI under the same account throw forbidden errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are causing is because of firewall issue i faced the same.

To resolve this error, change the firewall rule to **Enabled from all networks** or   **Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses and whitelist your client IP address**

**Update:**

Also check that AD uses have `Storage Table Data contributor` role assign to them

[image]

**Able to connect Successfully:**

[image]

Comment: I have reproduced the same error code as yours and gave the steps to resolve it. May I know what is your specific requirement or any other issue that you're facing? So I can update my answer accordingly?